# Vega: extract two different properties from source data

Tags: data-visualization, vega, vega-lite

I'm trying to use Vega to visualise the results of a query from elasticsearch.

The actual response from elasticsearch will look like what's in the first data entry below, named "es_response". I need to split that response data into two different data, which I named `histogram_data` and `rule_data`

I tried using `format: { property: "..." }` to extract the values in each subdata (as shown below), but it's not allowed by the language.

I also tried using various combinations of Transforms to separate that data, but couldn't get any good result.

What's the best way to do that?

[Link to the original vega-lite source](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHnSxkeWNjCgIESMlgB9AE6XCy-cdNnz6atTu08PJUZwuruaIjLB43J7oqMYA2hpBZsCQmDjSAAyqkOzGAEwAHAC+qibJxgAsGVnGAKzVRSUpYNWV2Thl0kXxCQ3GAGwtxgCcAIz1SY0A7AM4eaPF48Z5000d6t2JpTiDy8ODY5tgw2nLeRP7jcNHma1NOQVdrgC6a92QhMg28MhKPmKWzg8gpAKOgxKx-jg4utXIFoeYANbIACekDAOGadAygPWwNB4NROCOaWxQXucMeJLJpK6VM65jE6CRHwJYChiUBkG0ugBOKUUWQxgs1jssAcfgFLwSkAAZtwbBg8M4oIQbNx3jY8CicMkPF4dL5YHQQmEIjYoqiqa46UCMDZ4YL2OgbGoOd94NxNIwlNQea8AB5KmWMZBiTSCzDFSCa96CgCOrHQP2Y+qoFslQK1Jig0uDoYdaig0YF2vjiZ8uh8qbAlrMNetEFh5i5jUbZkgfNQxaglls9kcEpJMrlCsDKrVH014d1wh8jjo6q+Sb+hpBYP+1cB9bbtvt2psrD+Lqlbo9Xp9AUHAbRJhJ5hzIbD2tX+PTUqLcYTSYrjFTlNfbdgRgAC8u2AKBny7Mpq3-cx3TEOVA3vPNtURFFI3fbUlG4VAvVBC1NxpDQKQKIA)

```
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "es_response",
      "values": {
        "aggregations": {
          "histogram": [
            {"a": 30, "b": 28},
            {"a": 40, "b": 55},
            {"a": 50, "b": 43},
            {"a": 60, "b": 91},
            {"a": 70, "b": 81},
            {"a": 80, "b": 53},
            {"a": 90, "b": 19},
            {"a": 100, "b": 87},
            {"a": 110, "b": 52}
          ],
          "percentiles": {
            "values": [
              {
                "key": 50,
                "value": 100
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "histogram_data",
      "source": "es_response",
       
      /*
       * This doesn't work, but I really wish it did
       */
      "format": { "property": "aggregations.histogram"}
    },
    {
      "name": "percentile_data",
      "source": "es_response",
 
      /*
       * Same here
       */
      "format": { "property": "aggregations.percentiles.values"}
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Vega-Lite right now which is tracked at https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5034.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. :)
Do you want to use the elasticsearch query via url?

Then you could create two named data entries and use the json ˋformatˋ Option to specify the root.

Or if you want the data to be inline you can use ˋdatasetˋ property.

More explanations can be found here: 
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/data.html